# Vimeo api requests to my local backend server if the item has been purchased

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I am going to migrate from my local wowza server to vimeo. I would like to know if there is possibility that vimeo-api requests to my server to know if the user has token_id to watch exact video before playing/streaming that video.

If vimeo is not able to check that the user is authenticated in my web site(not in vimeo) then how can I avoid of hacking of my video links (e.g. authenticated in my web site then get the video url and share it with others).

I have read vimeo API but unfortunately didn't found anything concerning this.

Note: I am not using embedded code I am using HLS stream from vimeo pro plan

which is giving me possibility to use the third part player application

Please help me if you faced with such a problem. Thank you very very much!

Comment: Hey I would love to answer more details, but I think you might be approaching the problem in the wrong direction. Can you write up the core problem you are trying to solve with this application callback? Are you trying to restrict access to a video based on their Vimeo user account?

Comment: Hi,
Yes I am trying to restrict access to video with existed token which i am generating on my side.
My Problem is to find the way that vimeo could check if the user has valid token before streaming video to user.

Comment: I don't think you should rely on Vimeo for that. What you can do is limit the Vimeo video to only be playable on your own domain, and then restrict access to those videos using your own token system.

Comment: I am going to use the link on Smart tv application. I am not sure that the domain restriction will work.

Comment: In most of those applications, you don't want to use the embed code. You should use direct video file links which are accessible in any of your video representations (such as https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos. With that system, you don't have to allow your videos to be embeddable at all, you can use them in the native tv player